# How to return only the first tag in my XML Parser?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, tags, return

How is it possible to return only the first tag from my XML? The XML is like that:

```
<destinationname>New York City</destinationname>
<destinationname>New York</destinationname>
<destinationname>New Jersey</destinationname>
```

This is all one vacation. Every vacation has a different number of destinationnames. Some only one, some 2-4 names... I always want to return only the first tag.

This is a part of my XML Parser:

```
// assign the $data by the $this->element
        switch ($this->element) {
            case "destinationname":
                $this->item['zielgebiet'] .= $data;
                break;
            }
```

In the moment it returns this: "New York CityNew YorkNew Jersey"

Help really appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = '
<root>
<destinationname>New York City</destinationname>
<destinationname>New York</destinationname>
<destinationname>New Jersey</destinationname>
</root>
';

$d = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$nodes = $d->destinationname;

print $nodes[0] . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `break;` statement in your outer loop. Or if you are in a function use `return $data;`

Answer (score 0):

very simple:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
echo $xml->destinationname[0];
```

see it working: http://3v4l.org/JUOU1